# Jhipster gateway Tests for forward service calls with MockRestServiceServer

Tags: junit, jhipster, spring-cloud

I was provided this post as an example of how to mock a request to a remote service and then stub a response. https://objectpartners.com/2013/01/09/rest-client-testing-with-mockrestserviceserver/ While I understand gist of it, it uses RestTemplate which I can inject with

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

I need to test that certain headers are forwarded when a call to JHipster Gateway occurs and it needs to be forwarded to a downstream service. It doesn't matter, for the purpose of this test, whether such service exist as long as ZuulFilter is activated.

for e.g. 
`client -> gateway -(add header) -> (mock) book service (has header?)` 
this is what I am trying to test from my gateway but I am not even sure how I can start the gateway and send a request to random service name that doesn't exist as well as trap that request. Note that I do enable discovery client and use resttemplate for downstream services if that matters. I haven't found any examples that do this or maybe I am looking at the wrong place.

Comment: Can you supply the code/test you have that isn't working?

Comment: thank you @JonRuddell but where do you actually test ZuulFilter here and how do you know the headers are forwarded. Most tests are for gateway controllers itself. I am actually using a fork of your sample gateway. The only thing modified is this https://github.com/abshkd/jhipster-sample-app-gateway/commit/622d8eee7d38553975a5da66b89f8b73eb2f3913 (I might have missed imports since I edited on phone)

Comment: Sorry I linked to the wrong file, https://github.com/abshkd/jhipster-sample-app-gateway/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/gateway/responserewriting/SwaggerBasePathRewritingFilterTest.java   You can assert that the filter will run with `assertTrue(filter.shouldFilter());`, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @JonRuddell I have the modified TokenRelayFilter that adds the header to RequestContext but I can't seem to `filter.run()` since I am missing some expectations for `ignoredHeaders`. I want to verify that the header I added to requestContext actually gets added. I am following the example of Swagger filter but for a  method similar to this https://github.com/abshkd/jhipster-sample-app-gateway/blob/622d8eee7d38553975a5da66b89f8b73eb2f3913/src/test/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/gateway/responserewriting/SwaggerBasePathRewritingFilterTest.java#L54 not able to get ProxyHelper added to ZuulContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While unit tests can be done it's much harder to call `filter.run()` because several preconditions are missing.

What I also missed was that there is no RestTemplate to mock in the gateway

What I did eventually was to use `spring-cloud-contracts`

1. create a stubbed service say `provider`
2. then add it to `zuul.routes.provider.*` settings
3. launch SpringbootTest with Webenvironment.DEFINED_PORT so I can have the whole context+servlet running
4. Use `RestAssured` to make the call to the gateway for the `provider` route.

The provider itself is the stubbed groovy DSL that simply checks if the header is present and if so respond with `HttpStatus.OK` This is done using `spring-cloud-contract`

I will be posting the example here https://github.com/abshkd/spring-cloud-sample-games